# Problemas con Webpack style loader

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

estoy usando Webpack y esta compilando todo ok, no tira errores ni nada pero los estilos de mi .css no se estan cargando en la web y por lo que entiendo es problema del style loader.

Cuando hago un npm start dev, compila todo ok, pero cuando abro el index.html no veo el background red reflejado en el sitio.

```
//Este es mi webpack.config.js

    const path = require("path");

    module.exports = {
        mode: "development",
        entry: "./src/index.js",
        output: {
            filename: "bundle.js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")

        },
        module: {
            rules: [
              {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
              },
            ],
          },
    };  



//Mi main.css

    body {
        background: red;
    }


//El ruteo al bundle en el index.html
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>


//Este es mi index.js, el app.js es mi app y el main.css es el estilo que estoy intentando cargar, solamente con un fondo rojo a modo de prueba

import './app/app';
import './main.css';
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme cualquier otra cosa que haga falta la puedo subir. Muchas gracias

Comment: Los estilos que estás cargando se aplican a tus componentes, no van a modificar tu documento principal, si los cargas dentro de un componente, los estilos estarán disponibles para ese componente.

Comment: Ahh perfecto, creo que entiendo lo que me decis. En ese caso, existe alguna forma para aplicarlo a mi documento principal sin tener que rutear el main.css en el index.html?

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es tener un componente padre que envuelve a tus demás componentes y aplicarle esos estilos a ese componente, aunque lo mejor seria rutearlo directamente en el index.html, en el caso de que quisieras modificar los estilos que suele agregar el navegador por defecto como margenes, tipografía, etc.